# Reading and assigning to a TensorArray in a while loop

Tags: python, tensorflow

In TensorFlow, I have a `tf.while_loop`, which involves the use of a `TensorArray`. I have written a minimal toy example to demonstrate an issue I am having.

For every loop, I want to read the value of one element in this array, add it to a tensor, and then assign the result to another element of the array. The `body` argument of the while loop is defined as the following function:

```
def loop_body(i, x, y):
    x = x.write(i, y + x.gather(indices=[i-1])))
    return i, x
```

`i`, `x` and `y` are initialised as:

```
i = tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.int32)
x = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=10)
x = x.write(0, [0, 0, 0])
y = tf.constant([1, 2, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
```

Now when I run my code and execute the while loop, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Inconsistent shapes: saw (?, 3) but expected (3,) (and infer_shape=True)
```

Why doesn't `x.gather()` give me a shape of (3,)? What should I do differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document has already described that `tf.TensorArray.gather()` will return selected values in the TensorArray **as a packed Tensor**.

> Returns:
>
> The in the TensorArray selected by indices, packed into one tensor.

So you will get a shape of (?,3). You can change it :

```
x = x.write(i, y + x.gather(indices=[i-1])[0])
# or
x = x.write(i, y + x.read(i-1))
```

In addition, there are some errors in your code. I'll give a complete example below.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def condition(i, x,y):
    return tf.less(i, 10)

def loop_body(i, x,y):
    x = x.write(i, y + x.gather(indices=[i - 1])[0])
    #or
    # x = x.write(i, y + x.read(i-1))
    return i+1, x, y

i = tf.constant(1)
x = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32,size=1, dynamic_size=True,clear_after_read=False)
x = x.write(0, [0., 0., 0.])
y = tf.constant([1, 2, 3], dtype=tf.float32)

i, x, y = tf.while_loop(condition, loop_body, loop_vars=[i,x,y])
x = x.stack()

with tf.Session():
    print(i.eval())
    print(x.eval())

#print
10
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 2.  4.  6.]
 [ 3.  6.  9.]
 [ 4.  8. 12.]
 [ 5. 10. 15.]
 [ 6. 12. 18.]
 [ 7. 14. 21.]
 [ 8. 16. 24.]
 [ 9. 18. 27.]]
```